# Cannot create the database file into a relative path

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, sqlite

I'm using System.Data.SQLite and Dapper to create a database for my WPF application.
I follow a tutorial and first set and create myself a database file in the following folder as:

C:\Users\myUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\Development\MySolution\MyProject\MyDB.db

Then I set the path at App.config as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Default" connectionString="Data Source=.\MyDB.db;Version=3;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The thing is when I debug or release, the new database file(where the application writes into) is created under:

C:\Users\myUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Development\MySolution\MyProject\bin\Debug

But I want it to be created under:

C:\Users\myUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Development\MySolution\MyProject\bin

**What I did so far:**

At code:

```
InitializeComponent();

string logPath = new FileInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location).DirectoryName;

logPath = Directory.GetParent(logPath.Trim('\\')).FullName;
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", logPath);
```

And I changed the App.config file as:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Default" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MyDB.db;Version=3;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

But apparently above doesn't work. I don't think Source is what I need here.

So my problem is during the compilation the MyDB.db is not copied into where I want it to but only under Debug. I need it to be created and be accessed from the parent folder. How can that be done?

Comment: I think the connectionString  has no effect where the database will created

Comment: @dmitriy Why do you think that?

Comment: @OP: Can you clearify if you actually create the DB in code or if you have a template db, that is expected to be copied to a specific folder during deployment? Also: Have you considered using [Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=net-5.0) ?

Comment: @GNZ Do right click on you db file in Solution Explore and select Properties. In Properties you can see Copy to Output Directory. It does copy to output folder (or no copy)

Comment: @Fildor It is actually template db not by code. But maybe I should create the db file and the table in the code. Can I then direct the new created db file into parent directory of the exe file?

Comment: That depends on where the exe file is located and what permissions the user has under which the exe is running. That's why it is commonly recommended to use the dedicated AppData directory.

Comment: @Fildor Yes in my case the app will be at: C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\myApp\app-1.3.1 So basically I want the db file under myApp not in app-1.3.1 folder. Because when the app updates it will create  app-1.3.2 folder so on. So I want the db file to stay in the common folder for all versions. In the current case the db file is always in Debug or Release folder which in turn appears in app-1.3.1. I want it to be created under myApp folder.

Comment: Have you considered what is supposed to happen if you update the DB Schema?

Comment: @Fildor I thought I can create a new table if table schema is changed or create new table for each version.  The reason is I thought is better to have a single database file. But Im not experienced in the topic.